# Share user profile between two windows on the same PC

Tags: windows, multi-boot

I have two Windows installations on my PC, one is my main and the other is with Insiders program activated.

Can I share user profile from my main windows to one with Insiders?

Comment: Not really.. but you can share the pictures, documents, videos, etc... The user profile has many windows specific settings in it (to include your user profile part of the windows registry).

Comment: As said above, you may share some parts, but not even the most important ones. But you will be risking a corrupted profile, as the Insider version is only beta-test.

Comment: You can Sync settings between two (or more) computers with Microsoft Accounts using Start, Settings, Accounts.   That is the limit of commonality between user profiles.

Comment: Sad that it is impossible. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Actually, in a Windows operating system it has always not been possible. This is not a Windows 10 limitation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot share an entire user profile folder between separate OS installs on a multi-boot system. This is because the user profile directory contains settings that are OS and OS-version specific. Connecting different versions, and even just different copies, of the same OS to a user profile directory will result in corruption and data loss.

Things you *can* do would include:

- Using symlinks to redirect the data directories of the profiles (Documents, Downloads, Desktop, etc) to a shared drive that both OSes have access to.
- Using OneDrive to sync your data. This works within the Windows system most completely, but also will take up the most space as each profile will need its own space to save its own copies of the offline files.